# Understanding java code with arrays

Tags: java, android

I created an array in android studio. What does the code below mean?

```
private question[] questionbank = new question[]{
    new question(R.string.question_africa, true),
    new question(R.string.question_oceans, false),
    new question(R.string.question_mideast, true),
    new question(R.string.question_america, false),
    new question(R.string.question_asia, true);
```

I initialized an array from a class called question shown below

```
public class question {
    private int TextInput;
    private boolean AnswerInput;
    private boolean hasCheated;


    public boolean isHasCheated() {
        return hasCheated;
    }

    public void setHasCheated(boolean hasCheated) {
        this.hasCheated = hasCheated;
    }

    public question(int holdsTextInput, boolean holdsAnswerInput) {
        this. TextInput = holdsTextInput;
        this.AnswerInput = holdsAnswerInput;
    }

    public int getTextInput() {
        return TextInput;
    }

    public boolean getAnswerInput() {
        return AnswerInput;
    }
    public void setTextInput(int holdsTextInput) {
        this.TextInput = holdsTextInput;
    }
    public void setsAnswerInput(boolean holdsAnswer) {
        this.AnswerInput = holdsAnswer;
    }
}
```

However, I wanted some clarification, for instance, what exactly was done here? Did I reference the class question and create an array called questionbank? Also if so why do I need to put in each value as a new question?

Comment: By the way class name should be in upper camel case

Comment: Search for the Google Java style guide; you're not following code conventions, and it makes the code much more difficult to read.

Answer (score 3):

> Did I reference the class question and create an array called questionbank?

You created an array that can only store objects of type `question`. The array is itself an object, and a reference to the array was assigned to the field named `questionbank`.

Note that the array doesn't have a name, it's just referenced from a field with that name. You can assigning the same reference to fields and variables of other names, and it would still be the same array.

> Also if so why do I need to put in each value as a new question?

In Java, an array of objects is actually an array of object *references*, so when you create an array, you don't actually create any objects.

That is why you have to create 5 instances of `question` and assign the references to them to the array.

If you didn't do that, you'd have an array of `null` values.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we will create a single object named `questionbank` which type is `Array` and which holds elements of `question` type.

 **Step-1:** By declaring a reference variable as bellow:

```
 private question[] questionbank.....;
```

`questionbank` holds the reference of a **single** object which type is `Array`. By this part **no objects** are created.

**Step-2:** By writing  bellow part we are creating a **new** single object of `Array` type which element type is **question**

```
  new question[]{......};
```

**Step-3:**  And finally we are initializing our newly created single array object by putting some `question` objects on it:

```
{
new question(R.string.question_africa, true),
new question(R.string.question_oceans, false),
new question(R.string.question_mideast, true),
new question(R.string.question_america, false),
new question(R.string.question_asia, true)..}
```

Here `new question(..)` using each time because before putting a `question` object in `questionbank` array object we need to create them using `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

> Did I reference the class question and create an array called questionbank?

```
question[] questionbank = new question[];
```

This means create an array named `questionbank` that will contain only `question` objects. The name is used to refer to the array later on:

```
question q = questionbank[0];  // get the first element from the array
```

An alternate example:

```
String[] arr = new String[5];
```

Here you created an array named `arr` that will contain only 5 Strings;

> if so why do I need to put in each value as a new question?

The `questionbank` array can only hold `question` objects. Therefore adding objects using `new question(...)` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you created an array called questionbank.

I think you're confused about the notion of a class. The "new" keyword is just a fancy way to call the question class's constructor:

```
public question(int holdsTextInput, boolean holdsAnswerInput)
```

Each time you call this constructor, you create a new *instance* of question. For example, the line of code:

```
new question(R.string.question_africa, true)
```

Creates an *instance* of the question class, with its TextInput field set to R.string.question_africa and its AnswerInput field set to true.

On the other hand, the line:

```
new question(R.string.question_oceans, false)
```

Creates an *instance* of the question class with TextInput set to R.string.question_oceans and AnswerInput set to false.

Because the "new" keyword was used both times, these two *instances* of question have no relation to each other; changing one won't change the other.

You don't necessarily have to call new every time. For example, you could do:

```
question q = new question(R.string.question_africa, true);
private question[] questionbank = new question[]{q, q, q, q, q};
```

But as you can see, each questions stored in the array really references the same object (q) so they'll have the same fields (TextInput, AnswerInput) and changing one element of the array would change all other elements of the array (because they all point to the same *instance* of question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try using proper casing for Class Names.

```
Question[] question = new Question[size];
```

Then you use Constructors or methods based on your requirement.

Constructor Access:

```
 question[0] = new Question(x,y,z);
```

Method access:

```
question[0] = new Question();
.
.
question[size] = new Question();

question[0].isHasCheated();
```